# Is there any parse statement in python similar to REXX PARSE

Tags: python, rexx

I'm looking for some like REXX PARSE to manage strings in Phyton.

Could anyone tell me if there is an extension of Phyton to manage the
string parsing at least similar to REXX PARSE?

for example :

How to PARSE a string in position and length in python

Thanks

Jason Cai

Comment: I'm sure if you search the web for 'parsing strings in Python' you'll get loads of answers. If none of those address the *specific* programming problem you have, then please come back and ask that question. Remember that SO is for programming problems that you have and have tried to address and that you can show your non-working code as well as an explanation of what you want it to do and what it actually is doing (or not doing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: No, there is no builtin parse equivalent where you can supply a template by which to break up a string.

There is a package [parse pyPI](https://pypi.org/project/parse/) which offers something akin to a template method of breaking a string apart, but the use of a template is as close as it gets.

You can definitely parse a string by position and length in python.  The example below uses slicing which simulates position and length by specifying the starting and ending position.

```
In: line = 'Here is some data in a string of exactly 54 characters'
a,b,c = (line[0:4],line[5:7],line[13:17])
print(f'a is "{a}", b is "{b}", c is "{c}"')

Out: a is "Here", b is "is", c is "data"
```

The equivalent parse statement in rexx would be:

```
****** ********************************* Top of Data **********************************
000001 /* rexx */ 
000002                                                                                 
000003 line = 'Here is some data in a string of exactly 54 characters' 
000004                                                                                 
000005 parse var line a 5 . 6 b 8 . 14 c 18 . 
000006                                                                                 
000007 say "a is '"||a||"', b is '"||b||"', c is '"||c||"'" 
000008                                                                                 
****** ******************************** Bottom of Data ********************************
```

```
Output:
a is 'Here', b is 'is', c is 'data'
***
```

I do not say this is a good way to do it, just **a** way. It is far better for you to learn the python way to do pythonic things rather than to approach them with a rexx mindset.